# Modifying request object in middlewares-Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a bunch of middlewares in my Node.JS application, is there any way to delete/modify `req.path` and be reflected in the next middlewares?

Please let me know if you need more clarification if my question is vague?

UPDATED:

even `req.path = 'foo'` is not changing my req.path after that line!

```
req.path = "foo";
console.log(req.path);// Here still it shows my original req.path not foo!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function requestDispatcher() {
  //default version was set to v1
  var defaultVersion = 'v1',
    re = /\/v\d/;
  return function(request, response, next) {
    var version = request.get('version');
    debug(request.url);
    // test if request.url has already contained version number
    if (!re.test(request.url)) {
      // if not define version number in http header then set default version
      // otherwise use the version number in the http header
      if (version === null || version === undefined) {
        request.url = ['/', defaultVersion, request.url].join('');
      } else {
        request.url = ['/', version, request.url].join('');
      }
    }
    debug(request.url);
    next();
  };
}
```

I use this trick to dispatch the request to specified version, and route to default version if not specified. this work for me

```
app.use(requestDispatcher());
app.use('/v1', require('./v1'));
app.use('/v2', require('./v2'));
```

Comment: I have not fully understood what you mean! Have you seen my updated question? What is `debug(request.url);` in your code? What does it do?

Comment: in express, req.path is a readonly property if you look into it's source code
defineGetter(req, 'path', function path() {
  return parse(this).pathname;
});

Comment: function defineGetter(obj, name, getter) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: getter
  });
};

Comment: that is said, if you want to change the path, and reflect the next middleware, use req.url instead of req.path, and debug is the module to logging stuff, it's better then console.log, you will always forget to delete the console.log after you write it

Comment: checkout my example, use req.url instead of req.path

Answer (score -1):

yes, just change `.path` to whatever you want. many official middleware and APIs, such as mounting, do exactly this. note that this is prone to break a lot of stuff if you don't know what you're doing!

Comment: even req.path = 'foo' is not changing my req.path after that line!

Answer (score -1):

yes. just delete or modify it. its a javascript object.

Comment: But it seems it does not reflect in next middleware! Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Should I pipe it as well or just changing it should reflect in the next middleware?

Comment: maybe req.path is a computed property? have you tried changing req.url ?

Comment: It seems I have a silly mistake, I just updated my question with what I'm doing; it seems even it does not modify `req.path` after this operation, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this isnt enough code to tell what you are doing wrong. you should remove all your code and try setting `req.path = 'poop'` and see if that works, then go from there